# Flutter: How to get selected position SVG icon from a SVG file that contain many icons

Tags: flutter, svg

I was planning to get an icon from a SVG file which contain many icons. For example we can use array method to detect which position of the icon we want to obtain. How can we achieve this in flutter ?

Here is how the SVG file inside look like :
[image]